# Show basic URDF model in Rviz2

Tags: ros2, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow the [URDF tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) on ROS2. To begin I've launched Rviz2 like this:

```
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2
```

But I'm not able to see my model.

- I've selected the Description File to be my .urdf model, which I'm adding below.
- I've selected the "Fixed Frame" to be "base_link" and that solves an error, but is not enough to see the model.

This configuration can be seen here: https://imgur.com/a/J9uHVVq

I'm also getting a warning that says "No tf data. Actual Error: Frame [base_link] does not exist."

What am I missing?

My  system is:

- Linux Desktop 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu
- ROS2 Dashing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348984/show-basic-urdf-model-in-rviz2/) by [mclzc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53398/mclzc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question.

The solution is in this thread:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1151#issuecomment-345687074

Doing the following solves the problem of not being able to see the model:

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

---

Originally posted by [mclzc](https://answers.ros.org/users/53398/mclzc/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0